# Find inconsistent and consecutive objects from List in C#

Tags: c#, loops, linq, for-loop, if-statement

I'm having trouble with getting a consecutive and nonconsecutive number from list. I'm sure it's pretty simple, but i can't get it.

If consecutiveNum=2, then if result from before last and last is equal, i need to throw an exception.

If nonConsecutiveNum=4, then if from 10 pieces there are 4 with same result, i need to throw an exception.

I'm trying with nested loops and couple checks, but i didn't succeeded at all. Same is for both cases, i tried a couple solutions with System.LINQ, but again i don't get the result i need.

**Thanks in advance to all of you!**

```
int consecutiveNum = 2;
int nonConsecutiveNum = 4;
int counter = 1;

var sensInfo = new ResultInfo()
{
     Product = CurrentLot.Info.Product,
     Result = code
};

if (consecutiveNum > 0)
{
   for (int i = ListSensors.Count + 1; i >= 0; i--)
   { 
       if (sensInfo.Result == ListSensors[i].Result)
       {
           counter++;
           if (counter >= consecutiveNum)
           {
               throw new Exception("Consecutive num");
            }
       }
   }
}

if (nonConsecutiveNum > 0)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < ListSensors.Count; i++)
     {
          for (int j = i + 2; j < ListSensors.Count - 2; j++)
          {
               if (ListSensors[i].Result == ListSensors[i+1].Result)
                   continue;
               if (ListSensors[i].Result == ListSensors[j].Result)
               {
                   counter++;
                   if (counter >= nonConsecutiveNum)
                   {
                       throw new Exception("NonConsecutive num");
                   }
               }
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: `if (sensInfo.Result == ListSensors[i].Result)` this will immediately throw an index out of range exception, since you start at ListSensors.Count + 1

Comment: Please could you edit the code in your post so it has more readable indentation?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, sorry.

Comment: Please don't throw exceptions for non-exceptional things. You should always try to avoid exceptions where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// consecutiveNum
for (int i = ListSensors.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{ 
    if (sensInfo.Result == ListSensors[i].Result)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter >= consecutiveNum)
        {
            throw new Exception("Consecutive num");
        }
     }
     else
     {
         counter = 1;
     }
}

// nonConsecutiveNum
IDictionary<int, int> resultCountDictionary = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach (var listSensor in ListSensors)
{
    if (resultCountDictionary.ContainsKey(listSensor.Result))
    {
        resultCountDictionary[listSensor.Result] = resultCountDictionary[listSensor.Result] + 1;
        if (resultCountDictionary[listSensor.Result] >= nonConsecutiveNum)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        resultCountDictionary.Add(listSensor.Result, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly off topic but a best practice worth pointing out, I wouldn't throw base Exception:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types

Answer (score 0):

**Consecutive:**

Using [MoreLinq's Window](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#window) function:

`ListSensors.Window(consecutiveNum).Any(x => x.Distinct().Count() == 1);`

**Nonconsecutive:**

`ListSensors.Any(x => ListSensors.Count(s => s == x) >= nonConsecutiveNum);`